# How can I add navigation in my lightbox gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've built a lightbox gallery for my website. I added arrows to the left and right of the current image that's selected. I need some guidance on how to make the left arrow select the previous image and the right arrow select the next image in the gallery. I've been experimenting and searching but I haven't been able to figure it out on my own. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

https://jsfiddle.net/fabfivefebby/2z9unx02/2/

```
var $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
var $image = $("<img>");
var $caption = $("<p></p>");
var $exit = $("<div><button id='exit'> x </button></div>");
var $buttonLeft = $("<button id='buttonLeft'> < </button>");
var $buttonRight = $("<button id='buttonRight'> > </button>");

$overlay.append($exit);
$overlay.append($buttonLeft);
$overlay.append($buttonRight);
$overlay.append($image);

 //2.2 A Caption
$overlay.append($caption);

 //2. Add overlay
$("body").append($overlay);

var updateImage = function (imageLocation, captionText) {
//1.2 Update overlay with the imagelinked in the link
$image.attr("src", imageLocation);

//1.3 Add Caption from alt. Get child's alt att and set Caption
$caption.text(captionText);

}

//1. Capture the click event on a link to an image
$("#stillGallery a").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var imageLocation = $(this).attr("href");
var captionText = $(this).children("img").attr("alt");

$index = $(this).parent().index();

  //this is calling that new Update overlay function above
 updateImage(imageLocation, captionText);

//1.1 Show the overlay
$overlay.show();

});

$buttonRight.click(function() {
console.log("testing");
});

$exit.click(function(){
$overlay.hide();
});

$overlay.click(function(){
$overlay.hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/2z9unx02/12/

First update your CSS classes as following,

```
#exit {
    color: white;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right:30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 100;
}

#buttonLeft, #buttonRight {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#buttonLeft {
    left: 10px;
}

#buttonRight {
    right: 10px;
}
```

Now, change your javascript as following,

```
//Problem: User when clicking on image goes to dead end
//Solution: Create an overlay with the large image

var $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
var $image = $("<img>");
var $caption = $("<p></p>");
var $exit = $("<div><button id='exit'> x </button></div>");
var $buttonLeft = $("<button id='buttonLeft'> < </button>");
var $buttonRight = $("<button id='buttonRight'> > </button>");

    $overlay.append($exit);
    $overlay.append($buttonLeft);
    $overlay.append($buttonRight);
    $overlay.append($image);

//2.2 A Caption
    $overlay.append($caption);

//2. Add overlay
    $("body").append($overlay);

var updateImage = function (imageLocation, captionText) {
    //1.2 Update overlay with the imagelinked in the link
    $image.attr("src", imageLocation);

    //1.3 Add Caption from alt. Get child's alt att and set Caption
    $caption.text(captionText);

}

//1. Capture the click event on a link to an image
$("#stillGallery a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var imageLocation = $(this).attr("href");
    var captionText = $(this).children("img").attr("alt");

    $index = $(this).parent().index();

      //this is calling that new Update overlay function above
     updateImage(imageLocation, captionText);

    //1.1 Show the overlay
    $overlay.show();
    $(this).parent("li").addClass("active");
});
$buttonLeft.click(function() {
    console.log("testing Left");
    var temp = $("li.active").parents("div.pic_wrapper").prev();
    var imageLocation = temp.find("a").attr("href");
    var captionText = temp.find("img").attr("alt");    
    updateImage(imageLocation, captionText);
    $("li.active").removeClass("active");
    temp.find("li").addClass("active");
});
$buttonRight.click(function() {
    console.log("testing");
    var temp = $("li.active").parents("div.pic_wrapper").next();
    var imageLocation = temp.find("a").attr("href");
    var captionText = temp.find("img").attr("alt");    
    updateImage(imageLocation, captionText);
    $("li.active").removeClass("active");
    temp.find("li").addClass("active");
});

$exit.click(function(){
    $("li.active").removeClass("active");
    $overlay.hide();
});

/*$overlay.click(function(){
    $overlay.hide();
});*/
```

As you can see, I am adding an `active` class to the `li` having the image shown in the fixed overlay. Upon click right button, you can use the `.next()` selector to select the next `li` element. Similarly, use `.prev()` selector to select the previous `li` element.

Comment: Thank you. I've got this working now but it seems to freeze up when I reach the very beginning or very end of the gallery. My vision is to have it cycle through and start over. I used index(); to get the position of the element. I was thinking of using an if statement along the lines of: if (temp.index() === -1) { something to bring the gallery back to the beginning}

Answer (score 0):

ok let's start

1st append a hidden span to overlay to catch the index of div conatin the img you clicked

```
// append span to get index
    $overlay.append('<span id="getimgcount"></span>');
```

in css display it to none

```
#getimgcount{
    display: none;
}
```

and ignore that line now .. cause it will hide overlay if we click on arrows .. you need to use **e.target** later

```
$overlay.click(function(){
    //$overlay.hide();
});
```

for right and left arrows  use

```
$(document).on('click','#buttonRight',function() {
var this_img_count = parseInt($('#getimgcount').text());    
    var getnextimg = $('.pic_wrapper').eq(this_img_count + 1).find('img').attr('src');
    var getnextp = $('.pic_wrapper').eq(this_img_count + 1).find('h1').text();
    $('#overlay').find('img').attr('src',getnextimg);
    $('#overlay').find('p').text(getnextp);
    $('#getimgcount').text(this_img_count + 1);

});
$(document).on('click','#buttonLeft',function() {
var this_img_count = parseInt($('#getimgcount').text());    
    var getprevimg = $('.pic_wrapper').eq(this_img_count - 1).find('img').attr('src');
    var getprevp = $('.pic_wrapper').eq(this_img_count - 1).find('h1').text();
    $('#overlay').find('img').attr('src',getprevimg);
    $('#overlay').find('p').text(getprevp);
    $('#getimgcount').text(this_img_count - 1);

});
```

you will need some if statments here to know if you reach first image and last image

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/2z9unx02/9/)